# extended asm: invalid instruction suffix for 'mov'

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

Using i686-elf-gcc and i686-elf-ld to compile and link.

`/tmp/ccyjfCee.s:25: Error: invalid instruction suffix for 'mov'
makefile:21: recipe for target 'Release/boot.o' failed`

When I tried to modify `movw %0, %%dx` to `movw $0x1, %%dx`. It compiled and linked successfully. So I wonder why there is something wrong with the line. In light of `.code16`, the offset address of pStr should be 16bit, which fits into `dx` register well. What's wrong with it?

```
__asm__(".code16\n");

void printString(const char* pStr) {
     __asm__ __volatile__ ("movb $0x09, %%ah\n\t"
                           "movw %0, %%dx\n\t"
                           "int $0x21"
                           :
                           :"r"(pStr)
                           :"%ah", "%dx");
}

void _start() {
     printString("Hello, World");
}
```

Comment: IIRC gcc does not ever produce 16-bit code - it's 32- or 64-bit only (depending on default configuration or the presence of -m32 or -m64 options).

Comment: @isedev But if it doesn't support 16-bit code, what does `.code16` do here? I just compared the final assembly code with or without `.code16`, they were different.

Comment: I said gcc does not _produce_ 16-bit code. So `void printString(const char* pStr)` will produce 32- or 64-bit assembly code. The GNU assembler does have (limited) support 16-bit code however and `.code16` tells the assembler that the subsequent language instructions are to be run in real-mode or 16-bit protected mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can use the `.code16gcc` directive to generate 16 bit code and the `%w0` substitution to force word sized register.

Note that the above will only let you create a program that will run in 16 bit real mode under DOS (after some postprocessing to get it to the proper format). If that's not what you want, you will need to use the appropriate OS system calls instead of `int 0x21` and not write 16 bit code.